# How to drop tables in slick cascade (postgreSQL)?

Tags: postgresql, scala, foreign-keys, slick, cascade

I'm using PostgreSQL. I need to drop the tables cascade, here is a code snippet from [Scala-Forklift](https://github.com/lastland/scala-forklift) I need to override it in order to drop tables despite unknown foreign keys:

```
override def reset = {
val drop = MTable.getTables(None, None, None, None).flatMap { s =>
  DBIO.sequence(s filter { t =>
      t.tableType != null && t.tableType.toLowerCase == "table"
    } map { t =>
      TableQuery(new DummyTable(_, t.name.name)).schema.drop
    })
  }
  val f = db.run(drop)
  Await.result(f, Duration.Inf)
}
```

But I don't know how. Is it possible with the slick schemas? If not, can you please give me an example how to do it with SQL integrated in this method for all Tables in "MTable"?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to declare your schema with the foreign key as following:

```
def aFK = foreignKey("artistid", artistFacebookId, artists)(_.facebookId, onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.Cascade)
```

You would also need to modify it in your PostgreSQL schema definition:

```
artistId     VARCHAR REFERENCES artists(facebookId) ON DELETE CASCADE,
```